# How to find out user pressed "enter" in text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to add text input's element to my array when user pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> key. but I don't know how to do that. I tried this if statements but they didn't work:

```
var val = $("#txbxfeeds").val();
if (val[val.length-1] == "\r") {
    alert("HI");
}
if (val[val.length-1] == "\n") {
    alert("HI");
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What makes you think that [ENTER] results in a CR or LF to be added to the input? You have to bind a `keydown`, `keypress` or `keyup` event, and check the value of `event.keyCode` or `event.which`: 13.

Comment: I used `KeyPress` event from `jquery` but I didn't write it here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest the following:

```
var vals = [];

$("#txbxfeeds").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        vals.push(this.value);
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q4CUf/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txbxfeeds").on('keyup', function(e) {
   //13 is the code for enter button

   var val = $(this).val(); // or this.value

   if(e.which == 13) {
    alert( val );
   }
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4CUf/1/)**

Read more about jQuery **[event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)**